# há alguma maneira de criar instanciar uma classe inteira que está dentro da classe principal?

Tags: java

```
public class mainPrime{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //-----------------------
        new mainPrime().instancePrime2();
        //------------------------  
        
    }
    
    public void instancePrime2() {
        new Prime2().iniciarJogador();
    }
    
    public class Prime2{
        
        public void iniciarJogador() {
            System.out.println("jogador iniciado!");
            
        }
        public void renderizarJogador() {
            System.out.println("jogador renderizado!");
            
        }
        public void playerDeath() {
            System.out.println("jogador morreu!");
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

(aqui nesse caso, eu estou instanciando apenas um método da Prime2 na mainPrime, e eu queria instanciar a Prime2 inteira dentro da mainPrime, para usar os métodos livremente, há alguma maneira de fazer isso ou nao? sou novo no Java e ainda estou aprendendo)

Comment: *"eu estou instanciando apenas um método da Prime2 na mainPrime"* esse conceito está errado **não se instanciam métidos, sómente se instanciam classes**, ou seja, ao fazer `new mainPrime().instancePrime2();` você está instanciando mainPrime e chamando o método instancePrime2. Seria o mesmo que `var instancia = new mainPrime();  instancia.instancePrime2()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é possível, basta que a declaração de sua classe interna não tenha o nível de visibilidade "public".

O que está tentando fazer é conhecido como classe interna ([`inner class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)).

Para instanciar uma classe interna, você deve primeiro instanciar a classe externa. Em seguida, crie o objeto interno dentro do objeto externo com esta sintaxe:

```
public class mainPrime{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //-----------------------
        mainPrime mp = new mainPrime();
        mainPrime.Prime2 p = mp.new Prime2();
        p.iniciarJogador();
        p.renderizarJogador();
        p.playerDeath();
        //------------------------  
        
    }
    
    //public void instancePrime2() {
    //    new Prime2().iniciarJogador();
    //}
    
    class Prime2{ //remover a palavra "public" nesta linha
        
        public void iniciarJogador() {
            System.out.println("jogador iniciado!");
            
        }
        public void renderizarJogador() {
            System.out.println("jogador renderizado!");
            
        }
        public void playerDeath() {
            System.out.println("jogador morreu!");
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Existem dois tipos especiais de classes internas: [`classes locais`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) e [`classes anônimas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Repare que fazendo desta forma agora não será mais necessário o método `instancePrime2()`. Pois estamos criando tudo dentro do método `main`. Então em minha implementação deixei comentado.

Sua classe mainPrime não segue a convenção de nomes de classes do java, pela [`convenção`](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) deveria ser: `MainPrime` e ter o nome do arquivo `MainPrime.java` igual ao nome da classe.

### Motivos para usar classes internas:

- É uma maneira de agrupar logicamente classes que são usadas apenas em
  um lugar: se uma classe é útil para apenas uma outra classe, então é
  lógico incorporá-la nessa classe e manter as duas juntas. Aninhar
  essas "classes auxiliares" torna seu pacote mais simplificado
- Melhora legibilidade e manutenção do código: aninhar pequenas classes em classes de nível superior coloca o código mais perto de onde ele é usado.